# Sum of subspaces is the smallest containing subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In sheldon Axler's book,

> Suppose $U_1+\cdots+U_n$ are subspaces of $V$. Then $U_1+\cdots+U_n$ is the
> smallest subspace of V containing $U_1+\cdots+U_n$

**I can't understand two parts of this definition**

- $U_1,\ldots,U_n\subseteq U_1+\cdots+U_n$
- $U_1+\cdots+U_n$ is the smallest subspace in $V$

Comment: It appears that you have misunderstood what it says. $U_1+\cdots+U_n$ is the smallest among all subspaces of $V$ that have $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ as subspaces.

Comment: if so, what about the second part. I can't imagine how this smallest subspace is

Answer (score 0):

The sum $U_1 + \cdots + U_n$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ that contains $U_1,\dots,U_n$ in the sense that if $W$ is some other subspace of $V$ that contains $U_1,\dots,U_n$, then $U_1 + \cdots + U_n \subseteq W$. Compare the $\subseteq$ with the $\leq$!

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly nontrivial result saying that a finite sum of subspaces is again a subspace, and that it is in fact the smallest subspace containing each of the summands.

So there will be two things to check.

You can use the subspace criterion for the first part.   That is, a nonempty subset of a vector space is a subspace if it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

For the second you need to prove that any subspace containing each of the summands contains the sum.  Another way of saying it is that it is the intersection of all the subspaces containing it.

Comment: I think this is their definition of the sum, not a result that needs to be derived.

Comment: I was thinking that they probably defined it as the set of all sums.  @Vercassivelaunos  Anyway that would be standard.